# Reverse each word in a string using C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, reverse

Ok, so this code almost works, only it messes up the end of every line.
For instance, if I have as my stdin a text file with these three lines:

```
This is a test
For you to see
How this code messes up
```

Output reads:

```
siht si a
tsetroF uoy ot
eeswoH siht edoc sessem
pu
```

Let me know if you catch anything
Thanks

```
void reverse(char *beg, char *end)
{
  while (beg<end)
  {
    char temp = *beg;
    *beg++ = *end;
    *end-- = temp;
  }
}


void reverseWords(char *str)
{
  char *beg = NULL;
  char *temp = str;
  while (*temp)
  {
    if ((beg == NULL) && (*temp != ' '))
    {
      beg = temp;
    }
    if (beg && ((*(temp + 1) == ' ') || (*(temp + 1) == '\0')))
    {
      reverse(beg, temp);
      beg = NULL;
    }
  temp++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Without even looking at your code it is obvious that the behaviour is that it is including the newline character at the end of each line as part of the last word in the line. Hence it places the newline as the first character of the last word resulting in the observed output. You need code to deal with the newline.

Comment: I changed the +1 to +2 in the second if statement, second time there is addition. seems to work

Answer (score 1):

New lines in your code are not taken into consideration.

In the code below I've changed all the occurrences of `*something == ' '` to a call to the newly added method `isWhiteSpace`, which returns true if the character being checked is either a space, a tab, a newline, or a carriage return character:

```
void reverse(char *beg, char *end)
{
  while (beg<end)
  {
    char temp = *beg;
    *beg++ = *end;
    *end-- = temp;
  }
}

int isWhiteSpace(char value)
{
  return value == ' ' || value == '\t' || value == '\r' || value == '\n';
}


void reverseWords(char *str)
{
  char *beg = NULL;
  char *temp = str;
  while (*temp)
  {
    if ((beg == NULL) && !isWhiteSpace(*temp))
    {
      beg = temp;
    }
    if (beg && (isWhiteSpace(*(temp + 1)) || (*(temp + 1) == '\0')))
    {
      reverse(beg, temp);
      beg = NULL;
    }
  temp++;
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I was convinced that I was building on your comment above, but obviously this won't be clear for other viewers. Thanks.

Comment: Note: Code could use a standard library function and `return isspace((unsigned char) value);`.  C has at least 6 whitespace characters.

Comment: @chux, thanks for your comment, I preferred to show the implementation for more clarity on what is happening. But of course using the CRT method is more appropriate.